# htaccess to allow pages to be visited via a redirect, but NOT directly

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, referer

I thought I had things set up correctly but I havent found a 'perfect' solution quite yet and wanted to see if anyone out there has done a similar setup.

I have a page that depending on the day of the week will redirect to other pages (which are are not publicly linked).  I do not want users to be able to get to the final page without going through the designated referer so that users cannot bookmark and pull-up Mondays page on Friday.  If they do so they'll be redirected saying that they cannot access it via a bookmark.

The main page is www.example.com/AB/  Upon visiting that page a user is automatically redirected to www.example.com/AB/123 or www.example.com/AB/123

What I would like to accomplish is to block access to the final pages if they are not referred to from the parent page.  The parent page, however, can be accessed from anywhere (referrer does not matter).

Thoughts?

Thank you!

### EDIT:

@olaf - Here's where I am at ...

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !mysite\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?q/? http://mysite.com/sorry-no-bookmarks/ [R=302,L]
```

disregarding days or timing, anything that is a subpage under "/q/..." should be redirected to the "no bookmarks" page if it did not come from somewhere (anywhere) on mysite.com.  In addition I would like to keep anything thats subpaged under "/n/..." freely accessible from anywhere (outside referers included).  Works mostly okay with chrome, but firefox and IE are blocking things regardless.  fun times!

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean is to redirect into the abuse text the user that have linked to `/AB/$dynamic` in which not came from `/AB/`? Give this a try:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !example.com/AB/?$ [NC]
RewriteCond ^/AB/([a-z0-9-_]+)/? abuse.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you stay on the same server, I wouldn't redirect but do an internal rewrite instead

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} 1
RewriteRule ^AB/?$ /AB/monday.html [L]

RewriteCond %{TIME_WDAY} 2
RewriteRule ^AB/?$ /AB/tuesday.html [L]

# and so on ...
```

or name the daily files `1.html` for monday, `2.html` for tuesday, ... and do it in one rule

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule ^AB/?$ /AB/%{TIME_WDAY}.html [L]
```

Comment: looks like that is close I think.  And I may now be rethinking some things as well.

example.com/AB/example1 will redirect to example.com/AB/monday OR example.com/AB/tuesday OR example.com/AB/wednesday etc etc.

The only way a user should ever get to monday, tuesday, or wednesday is if the referer is example.com/AB/example1.  If they came from another referer, no referer (bookmark), it should redirect to example.com/sorry where I explain the pages cannot be visited directly.

Comment: And thank you for the help olaf!  the redirect part is actually being handled by a plugin, just looking to block out those trying to access direct.  The end result will have daily coupons and we do not want visitors trying to use Fridays coupon on Monday by pulling it up via a bookmark.

Comment: @user2246563 Don't rely on the referrer alone, because with [`wget --referer`](http://www.gnu.org/software/wget/manual/wget.html#index-http-referer-97), you can supply any referrer you like. Use the current weekday, which is supplied from the server's time, in your rules as well. When you grant access depending on the weekday, then the referer isn't important anymore.

Comment: thanks again!  I was trying to keep my description as simple as possible thus I wasnt relying on date, and being okay with using the referrer alone.

day of the week is not the only qualifier.  Other pages may be limited to only minutes or hours as well.  IE /AB/123 works for 10 minutes then /AB/456 takes over, then /AB/789 -- thus I cant rely on day.  

Also it will be primarily mobile users,so I am not overly concerned with the wget --referer